# Fantasy book where main protagonists are brothers. One a warrior, the other a mage

Tags: story-identification, books

It has been quite a while, but I remember being enthralled. I do remember one other thing about the book--the mage brother was physically weak and had to be helped around by the warrior brother.

I am interested in finding out the author, and the book.

Comment: Do you remember any more details? The question as it currently stands is pretty vague and could probably cover a lot of different books.

Comment: I concur. Unfortunately it has been about 13 years. I do remember that they were humans. I cannot say explicitly that there were no fantasy creatures (dwarfs, etc...), but I have no memory of anything but humans. Also, +1 for your name :)

Comment: Do you remember if the plot involved a board game where spells were allocated using small iron bars, and the villain was cat-related?

Comment: @SeanDuggan colour me intrigued. What story is that?

Comment: @frodoskywalker: *Brothers Majere*, one of the prelude novels where it's just Caramon and Raistlin (and a throwaway Kender character, Earwig Lockpicker). And I realized after looking at the plot summary that I got confused. The Lord of Cats was helping them.

Comment: I do not remember anything about that :)

Comment: @JClark4321 If you're not sure you remember anything but humans, I have doubts about whether this is it. The DragonLance world is crawling with Kender, Half-Elves, Minotaurs etc. Not many dragons though.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Sounds like Caramon and Raistlin Majere from the [*Dragonlance Chronicles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonlance_Chronicles) books. First one is [*Dragons of Autumn Twilight*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragons_of_Autumn_Twilight). Raistlin was the mage, in poor health. Caramon was his twin brother, a big, strong fighter.

> A group of old friends and new companions meet and begin their journeys to become the Heroes of the Lance. They enter Xak Tsaroth, find the Disks of Mishakal, are captured, meet Gilthanas, invade Pax Tharkas, meet Elistan, who becomes the first cleric of Paladine, incite a successive slave revolt, and kill a Dragon Highlord.

Comment: Oh thanks for the suggestion. I will look into those and let you know soon!

Comment: I loved the entire set of Dragonlance novels. I lost *many* hours at a time entranced by the action.

Comment: I disagree with using the term "lost" here. I consider none of my time lost while in a good fantasy story line :)

Comment: @JClark4321 **"good"** is the keyword, here.

Comment: While I realize it's a wiki, that has to be one of the *worst* summarizations of a great book I've ever seen.

Answer (score 13):

I also immediately thought of the Dragonlance world, but the original trilogy (the Chronicles) features several more protagonists and I don't remember Caramon and Raistlin standing out that much from the others.

Instead, I feel that [Dragonlance Legends](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragonlance_Legends), also by Margaret Weis and Tracy Hickman, is a better fit. It forms a sequel trilogy to the original three books, but perhaps the asker read only this.

Comment: More likely he read at least part of both trilogies, and is remembering them collectively.  If he'd only read Legends, he wouldn't remember Caramon helping Raistlin, since they were adversaries by then.

Comment: Oh sad day. Bad spoiler, bad.

Comment: Also, I think Caramon and Raistlin stand out to me because I am very into traditional magical types of heros. Especially the "glass cannon" type of very powerful but weak mages.

Comment: @JClark4321 Did the Wikipedia link spoil you? If so, apologies. Should I add a warning?

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't 13 years ago, but it fits your description. It is [*The Prophecies Series*] by Michael Rothman, the first book is [*Heirs of Prophecy*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007MW34X4). There are three books in the series. They chronicle the Riverton family.

> The Riverton family had been enjoying a simple summer vacation when, through a fluke of nature, they found themselves in a strange new land.
>
> The Riverton brothers quickly realize that in this world, they have gained unusual powers. Powers that their parents fear will attract the attention of Azazel himself - the merciless wizard who brutally controls this world.
>
> The two brothers soon learn that an ancient prophecy has finally been initiated by their arrival in Trimoria. As the heirs of this prophecy, they are destined to lead the armies of men, dwarves, elves, and even a misfit ogre against the prophesied demon horde.
>
> Only one thing stands in their way.
>
> The evil wizard who has learned of their presence, and has sent assassins to wipe them from existence.