Fantasy novel (trilogy). Two brothers, one good and one evil
About 15 years ago I was given some books to read and I remember loving them but can't remember much detail
I'm pretty sure it was a fantasy trilogy. The first book was about a poor girl determined for a better life type of thing, ended up being queen I think, had 2 sons, one good but a bit dim, one evil, mother was also evil. The good brother ended up killing the evil brother (?) with something he wore on his wrist.
I think there was quite a bit of mention about there being a god. The good brother ended up injured at one point and a good Samaritan nursed him back to health in a cottage in the woods.

Fantasy trilogies with brothers are two a penny; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/92961/fantasy-book-where-main-protagonists-are-brothers-one-a-warrior-the-other-a-ma

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover art of any of the books?

What is fantasy about it?
